# Where can I find OEM inserts for Toyota wiper blades?

Tags: toyota, parts, part-identification, windshield-wipers

I'd like to replace the wiper blade inserts on the original Toyota Highlander 2006 Hybrid blades.  Not all dealers carry these, I'd like to order them online, but cannot seem to find anyone that carries all three, (front right, front left, and rear).

How can I locate the exact part numbers for these and where might these be purchased online?

I would think this would be easy, but after spending over an hour searching, the best I could find was the rear and passenger front, but no driver front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MD6380's answer is for the blade, not for the insert (rubber in the Toyota parts catalog), but they seem to state that there are no inserts available for theses.

Based on the [ToyoDIY.com](http://www.toyodiy.com) website, it's should be these

- RH: 85214‑53040 (03/2005 - 04/2006) or 85214‑53041 (06/2006 - )
- LH: 85214‑48010
- REAR: 85214‑31010

Answer (score 1):

The fronts are listed on Toyota's website.  I'm not sure why the rear isn't, but it sound like you already have the part number for the rear.

http://www.toyota.com/toyota-owners-online-theme/pdf/WiperBlade2011and2007.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If your blade inserts are the same style as my MR2 uses, you may just be trying too hard.  My dealer doesn't carry the blade inserts for my car, but they have longer versions and I just cut off the non-locking side to fit...  I think the longer ones cost about 10 cents more, but I don't feel too bad about the lost 20 cents since I waste more than that in the vending machine at work.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

My dealer stopped selling the inserts, but I bought some online from a reputable online Toyota discount dealer.  The drivers side blade was correct, but the passenger side (shorter) was much different than normal, and I crammed it in, but it just smeared the rain.  I don’t know why this happened, but be careful![image]
The left blade in my photo is the end of the blade I received for my 2000 Camry is the one that doesn’t fit correctly or wipe correctly.
Jim S